# Flutter Class not working

Tags: class, dart, widget, flutter

I'm new to Flutter/Dart so might not be using all the correct key words, but I've run into a problem where I get a red line under class **'FirstPageState'** extends State. This prevents me from debugging the app so I've come here to hopefully receive a solution!

Here's my code for 'FirstPage.dart'

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

String _FirstPageText = 'Exchange Rates';

class First extends StatefulWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  FirstPageState createState() => new FirstPageState();
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text(_FirstPageText),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        ),
        body: new FeedWidget(),
        ),
      );
  }
}

class FirstPageState extends State<First> {

Future<String> getData() async {
  var response = await http.get(
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
  );

}

}
```

Thank You :)

Comment: move your build method to `FirstPageState` class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you read the "red line", you'll see an error, likely around `State` being [an abstract class](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#abstract-classes) that expects [one or more methods to be defined](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#abstract-methods):

> Instance, getter, and setter methods can be abstract, defining an interface but leaving its implementation up to other classes

In this case, I believe [`State` expects the `build` method](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State-class.html). You might want to take a look at the [documentation behind `StatefulWidget`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html), which describes what is necessary:

> ```
> class YellowBird extends StatefulWidget {
>   const YellowBird({ Key key }) : super(key: key);
>
>   @override
>   _YellowBirdState createState() => new _YellowBirdState();
> }
>
> class _YellowBirdState extends State<YellowBird> {
>   @override
>   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     return new Container(color: const Color(0xFFFFE306));
>   }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Any class which you extends from State<...> have to override the build() method. You have override the build() method at wrong place and wrong way.

You just need to update the code as shown below and your code will work.

```
class First extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  FirstPageState createState() => new FirstPageState();
}
class FirstPageState extends State<First> {

  Future<String> getData() async {
    var response = await http.get(
        'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text(_FirstPageText),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        ),
        body: new FeedWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```